# How to convert folder containing .py, .json, .spec, .png to .exe?

Tags: python, exe

I have one folder in that contains files like `.py`, `.json`, `.spec`, `.png`. I want to convert this folder to `.exe` format.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Go through this [link](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) to know how to post question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools to convert a folder into a self-extracting archive. But since your question is tagged with python, I assume you'd like to script this process.

Without questioning WHY you want to do this, here are the building blocks:

- traverse through the folder and grab the files you'd like to add to an archive
- use a unique boundary string to separate the files. This is the same as the "tar" command in Linux
- write a generic self extracting tool and use that as the template EXE. this file should expect to read from itself. You may use another locator string near the end of the EXE file to separate the code and data sections
- your python script will append the data to the self extracting EXE

This is the same steps of writing certain virus. Again, I won't ask too many questions, but you should have a starting point now.